# When describing someone is 'suspicious'

Tags: word-usage

If I say just 'he is suspicious'

Could that mean

a) he thinks someone else did something dishonest of wrong

b) he looks like he did something wrong or dishonest

at the same time?

For example,

a) He's saying that he's innocent, but people are suspicious

(people think he did something wrong)

b) People think he did it, and I also think that he's suspicious

(I think he did something wrong)

Do they make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, suspicious can mean both those things, depending on what context it is used in.

Both the examples provided by you are also correct usages of suspicious, and make sense.